# Broadcom 4311 wireless card on Dell 9400 (E1705) not working

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, dell, broadcom

I am following the advice of seasoned Ubuntu professionals and am posting my question here with a printout of a script posted by Wildman et al. I am grateful to you for your offer to help. Here is the link to the script output: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7706664/

I have tried numerous suggestions posted here on askubuntu.com. My device is not blacklisted. I can see it listed when I run `lshw -C network`:

```
*-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=b43-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:dfdfc000-dfdfffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:14:22:f5:71:64
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=b44 driverversion=2.0 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.104 latency=64 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:17 memory:df9fe000-df9fffff
```

Any advice you can offer at this point would be greatly appreciated. I believe I have tried just about every suggestion on the forum. I got the ethernet connection working, and I feel I am close on the wireless connection, also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Reboot

Comment: Wildman that solved the problem. Thank you so much. You really are the Wildman!

Comment: Please accept the answer so that anyone looking for this solution can find it. Thanks